# What's the runtime (in Big O notation) for Array reversal (java)?

Tags: java, big-o

What's the runtime (in Big O notation) for Array reversal for the below java code?

```
void reverse(int[] array){
   for(int i=0;i<array.length/2;i++){
     int other = array.length-i-1;
     int temp = array[i];
     array[i] = array[other];
     array[other] = temp;
   }
}
```

Comment: `O(n)` because it grows *linearly* with the length of `array`.

Comment: Very obviously O(n), all operations are 1, and you loop with the size of the arr, even with O(n/2) = O(n)

Comment: Simple approach.  Count the operations performed for an array of size N.  Is it proportional to N?  If so, the algorithm is `O(N)`.

Comment: Thanks @StephenC. This is what I was not sure about if proportions are discarded or not. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Harry - If you weren't sure of that, then you should find / read a good explanation of what Big O notation actually means.